# Getting SQL Error: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis in sql developer

Tags: sql, oracle

While running the below command in the oracle sqldeveloper am getting the missing right parenthesis error how to resolve it?

Error starting at line 7 in command:

```
create table usersmorethanone as (
select a.id,a.login,a.email,a.realm_id,a.registration_date 
from CORE.dps_user a 
join (select login,count(*) 
from CORE.dps_user 
GROUP BY login 
HAVING count(*) > 1) b on a.login=b.login order by 2)
```

```
Error at Command Line:7 Column:219
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Comment: Count the `(` and `)`. Same number?

Comment: Your subquery `b` doesn't have an alias for the count column. I think you don't need to select the count at all.

Comment: Unrelated, but: you don't need to put the SELECT statement between parentheses

Answer (score 1):

Removed the orderby and now the query is working fine and giving results.

Corrected query:

```
CREATE TABLE usersmorethanone
    AS
        SELECT
            a.id,
            a.login,
            a.email,
            a.realm_id,
            a.registration_date
        FROM
            core.dps_user a
        JOIN (
            SELECT
                login,
                COUNT(*)
            FROM
                core.dps_user
            GROUP BY
                login
            HAVING
                COUNT(*) > 1
        ) b ON a.login = b.login;
```